# Draw Hexagon based on zip code in google map?

Tags: google-maps, polygon, zipcode

I want to draw Hexagon polygon on google map based on zip code (single lat, long). How can I get other lat long so I can pass it to polygon array based on single lat long, It would be also based on any radius e.g. 15 miles or 15 km.

Here is sample google map image.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use code from Mike Williams' [eshapes](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/eshapes.htm) ported to v3.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/9hj2ngv7/)

from his documentation for a `RegularPoly`:

> Plots a regular polygon (e.g. pentagon, square, octagon) with a specified centre, radius, number of vertices, and rotation.

Parameters

- latlng    Centre of the shape
- radius    Length of radius in metres
- vertexCount   Number of vertices, e.g. 5 for a pentagon
- rotation  Degrees of rotation.
  When zero or omitted the southern edge of the shape is horizontal
- color Color parameter for polyline
- weight    Weight parameter for polyline
- opacity   Opacity parameter for polyline
- opts  Options parameter for polyline

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var map;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  codeAddress("Atlanta, GA");
}

function codeAddress(address) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      // === Hexagon ===
      var point = results[0].geometry.location;
      var hex1 = google.maps.Polygon.RegularPoly(point, 25000, 6, 60, "#000000", 1, 1, "#ff0000", 0.5);
      hex1.setMap(map);
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

// original code from Mike Williams' eshapes.js
// http://econym.org.uk/gmap/eshapes.htm
// ported to the Google Maps Javascript API v3
google.maps.Polygon.RegularPoly = function(point, radius, vertexCount, rotation, strokeColour, strokeWeight, Strokepacity, fillColour, fillOpacity, opts) {
  rotation = rotation || 0;
  var tilt = !(vertexCount & 1);
  return google.maps.Polygon.Shape(point, radius, radius, radius, radius, rotation, vertexCount, strokeColour, strokeWeight, Strokepacity, fillColour, fillOpacity, opts, tilt)
}
google.maps.Polygon.Shape = function(point, r1, r2, r3, r4, rotation, vertexCount, strokeColour, strokeWeight, Strokepacity, fillColour, fillOpacity, opts, tilt) {
  var rot = -rotation * Math.PI / 180;
  var points = [];
  var latConv = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(point, new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat() + 0.1, point.lng())) * 10;
  var lngConv = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(point, new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat(), point.lng() + 0.1)) * 10;
  var step = (360 / vertexCount) || 10;

  var flop = -1;
  if (tilt) {
    var I1 = 180 / vertexCount;
  } else {
    var I1 = 0;
  }
  for (var i = I1; i <= 360.001 + I1; i += step) {
    var r1a = flop ? r1 : r3;
    var r2a = flop ? r2 : r4;
    flop = -1 - flop;
    var y = r1a * Math.cos(i * Math.PI / 180);
    var x = r2a * Math.sin(i * Math.PI / 180);
    var lng = (x * Math.cos(rot) - y * Math.sin(rot)) / lngConv;
    var lat = (y * Math.cos(rot) + x * Math.sin(rot)) / latConv;

    points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat() + lat, point.lng() + lng));
  }
  return (new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: points,
    strokeColor: strokeColour,
    strokeWeight: strokeWeight,
    strokeOpacity: Strokepacity,
    fillColor: fillColour,
    fillOpacity: fillOpacity
  }))
}

function EOffset(point, easting, northing) {
  var latConv = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(point, new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat() + 0.1, point.lng())) * 10;
  var lngConv = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(point, new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat(), point.lng() + 0.1)) * 10;
  return new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat() + northing / latConv, point.lng() + easting / lngConv)
}

function EOffsetBearing(point, dist, bearing) {
  var latConv = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(point, new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat() + 0.1, point.lng())) * 10;
  var lngConv = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(point, new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat(), point.lng() + 0.1)) * 10;
  var lat = dist * Math.cos(bearing * Math.PI / 180) / latConv;
  var lng = dist * Math.sin(bearing * Math.PI / 180) / lngConv;
  return new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat() + lat, point.lng() + lng)
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could calculate and draw hexagon area based on lat/lng using the following approach:

```
function drawHexagon(map,position,radius){
    var coordinates = [];
    for(var angle= -90;angle < 270; angle+=60) {
       coordinates.push(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(position, radius, angle));    
    }

    // Construct the polygon.
    var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: coordinates,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    polygon.setMap(map);
    map.setCenter(position);
}
```

**Complete example**

```js
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(33.748589, -84.390392);  //Atlanta, GA, USA 
    var radius = 50 * 1000; //radius in meters
    drawHexagon(map,position,radius);
}



function drawHexagon(map,position,radius){
    var coordinates = [];
    for(var angle= -90;angle < 270; angle+=60) {
       coordinates.push(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(position, radius, angle));    
    }
  
    // Construct the polygon.
    var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: coordinates,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    polygon.setMap(map);
    map.setCenter(position);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
 html, body, #map-canvas {
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```